# How to do dynamic nested serialization in django rest framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

For an API that serves multiple quizzes, each of which have varying questions, I have the following models:-

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

```
class QuizQuestion(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(related_name="questions", Quiz)
    question = models.CharField()
```

```
class QuizCompletion(models.Model):
    completed_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
```

```
class QuizAnswer(models.Model):
    quizquestion = models.ForeignKey(QuizQuestion)
    quizcompletion = models.ForeignKey(related_name="answers", QuizCompletion)
    answer = models.CharField()
```

I am trying to write the serializers and views I need in order to allow the QuizCompletion to be created but I'm having some problems with the validation side of things, as the questions each quiz has (and therefore the answers that it needs) are dynamic. So, each quiz has different questions.

My serializers look like this:-

```
class QuizQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = QuizQuestion
        fields = ["question"]
```

```
class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuizQuestionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ["name", "questions"]
```

```
class QuizAnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    quizquestion = QuizQuestionSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = QuizAnswer
        fields = ["quizquestion"]
```

```
class QuizCompletionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    quiz = QuizSerializer()
    answers = QuizAnswerSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = QuizCompletion
        fields = ["completed_by", "quiz", "answers"]
```

The problem is, how do I validate the request when a user tries to complete a quiz to make sure that they've given an answer to all of that Quiz's questions?

My gut feeling is that I need to either:-

a) do it in a custom validate() method on the QuizCompletionSerializer

or

b) write a custom Validator class which will be used for the answers field on the QuizCompletionSerializer

But I'm getting a bit lost and not sure if I'm thinking of this the right way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both ways are the same, only difference is in `validate` method, you can access `quiz` attributes, which IMO not needed. I would have implemented like this:

```
class QuizCompletionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    quiz = QuizSerializer(read_only=True)  # I only want to show quiz data on get request
    answers = QuizAnswerSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = QuizCompletion
        fields = ["completed_by", "quiz", "answers"]

    def validate_answers(self, attrs):
        quiz = self.context['quiz']
        if len(attrs) != quiz.questions.count():
            raise ValidationError(...)
        return attrs
```

Also, I would send the `quiz` from view to serializer through [`context`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context). I would get the quiz id by urls like this:

```
path('/quiz/<int:quiz_pk>/answer', QuizAnswerView.as_view())
```

Then pass the `quiz_pk` information to the context like this:

```
class QuizAnswerView(ListCreateAPIView):
     ...
     def get_extra_context(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_extra_context(**kwargs)
        context['quiz'] = Quiz.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs['quiz_pk'])
        return context
```

Comment: This makes some sense. But it's only going to tell the user that they "haven't answered all of the questions". I was rather hoping for something similar the response you get when you don't fill in a required field - something like "This field is required" and the ID of the question that hasn't been answered.

Comment: How would you design your error response? Maybe you can build a list of missing questions from this method and raise a custom [error response](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) from this method.

Comment: OK, I'm getting somewhere with this method. I've generated a custom error response and all is working well. I just have one small question though - why do you put the quiz into the serializer context instead of forcing it to be passed in to the init method of the serializer so that we can guarantee we have access to it?

Comment: I prefer not to change too much, because if I had modified the serializer constructor, then I had to change more (both serializer and view), where is now I only change in one place (view) and rest is taken care of (passing the value to serializer), also it is preferred method by DRF as well. But again its up to you, because performance wise, it should not make any difference.

Comment: Makes sense. The only risk is that, if you rely on it being in the context (in the serializer) and it's not (because you didn't add it in the view) then you'll have problems.